# what is the meaning of "url"+"serialized form" in $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Good day, I've just started using ajax in jquery. what is the meaning of "url"+"serialized form" in $.getJSON? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: there is no "url"+"serialized form" in `$.getJSON`

Comment: I have seen a video with regards to editable tables.

this is one particular code that confused me. 
the code is something like this:

$.getJSON(url+input, function(){
});

where url is a var for an url 
and input is a var for ('form').serialize();

Comment: It'd help if you share the video and of course include in your question the time in the video where you saw this code.

Comment: here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FNyIz37j3I
the time is around 26:08.

thank you very much for the replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a $.getJSON thing it is a jQuery function to get the query string of form field values.

For example:

```
<form action="javascript:alert('OK');" method=”get”>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

a `$('form').serialize();` will return `field1=<value>&field2=<value>`

So in the example you mentioned, this must have been used to generate the url where the JSON needs to be fetched. For example, if you have a base url:

```
var url = 'https://example.com/some-path?q=something';
```

and you want to add some parameters to it from the values in the form:

```
$.getJSON(url + $('form').serialize(), function(json) {
  ....
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I understand that part. 
but I was confused when he didn't use the serialized form as data of the ajax: for example $.getJSON(url, input, function(){ }); 
instead he used it like this $.getJSON(url+input, function(){ });

Comment: so the $('form').serialize is still used as a data?

Comment: If you look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ the data can be an object or a string. It also does not have to be provided. Some people also just append it to the URL instead of passing it as data (object/string) since there is no POST request, it is only GET, so parameters can be in the URL

Comment: I now understand. I appreciate your help. thank you very much!